# General purpose algorithms that make use of presorting and their efficiency

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Is the following statement true or false?

> General purpose algorithms that make use of presorting can never have
>   a worst-case efficiency that is better than O(nlogn)

I assume it to be true. Because the big O for this is O(nlogn)

Answer (score 0):

The statement is true if the later phase won't be more time consuming than `O(n log n)`. Also if there are some other speicial-purpose sorting algorithms like Radix sort, Counting sort, Bucket sort, Pancake sorting which are efficient(generally linear time) than comparison based sorting algorithms(`O(nlogn)`).

Comment: I haven't learned Radix sort, Counting sort, Bucket sort, Pancake sorting. So I assume the statement is true until this point.

Answer (score 0):

The implication of the statement is that non-comparison linear sorts (time complexity O(n)) such as radix sort can't make use of presorting. Although the number of operations for radix sort is not affected by presorting, the cache locality of sequential write operations due to presorted data will improve the performance.